# KineticJS: Shadow without shape?

Tags: kineticjs

In [KinectJS](http://kineticjs.com/), how do you create a shadow (i.e., translucent shape with blurred edges) without drawing the shape that "casts" it?

At first I thought that one could just let the shape cast a shadow but set opacity of the shape itself to zero. Like so:

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    opacity: 0,
    shadowEnabled: true,
    shadowBlur: 10,
    shadowOpacity: 0.6
});
```

However, this does not work because it appears that the final shadowOpacity is multiplied by the shape's own opacity value. So if shape opacity==0, then final shadowOpacity = 0.6 * 0 == 0. Which means that the shadow ends up invisible too.

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can have shadow without shape unless you build your custom shape with blurry touches. You can hide the main shape outside of view though like the following. I do not recommend this for many shapes though.

```
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.1-beta2.js"></script>
    <script>
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 200
      });

      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

      var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: -120,
        y: -90,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'blue',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        shadowColor: 'black',
        shadowBlur: 10,
        shadowOffset: 150,
        shadowOpacity: 0.5
      });

      layer.add(rect);
      stage.add(layer);

    </script>
```

Comment: Now that's what I call thinking outside the box :-) Perhaps not what I was looking for, but a cool hack nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the Blur filter.  This will be released with v4.3.4 later this month (March 2013).  Shadows aren't a good a mechanism to create blurred edges due to the w3c spec.

Comment: Is this out yet? Can't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I remember doing this by changing the kinteticjs framework to create transparent buttons with shadows.  I changed the specific shape methods to allow for filling in the opposite direction.  Whenever you fill in the opposite direction it removes that shape from any other shapes in the same fill.

Answer (score -1):

I think, this can help you: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-shadows/.

Comment: In the linked example all shadow casting shapes are visible. What I'd like to have though is a shadow without the shape that produces it. Or alternatively, it could be a filter applied to shape that blurs its edges. Which again is something that I cannot find in the API.